# Why does Python CGIHTTPServer on Ubuntu return my script if GET parameter has a slash character?

Tags: python, ubuntu, cgi

I'm trying to run some basic CGI with CGIHTTPServer.  I want to pass a parameter with special characters in (specifically URLs, but I don't think this matters particularly).  My set up works with POST, but not with GET. GET returns the contents of my CGI script instead.  What am I doing wrong?

I'm getting this issue on Ubuntu 12.04 with Python 2.7.3.  Running the same code on Windows or Raspbian works ok.

Here's my examples.  My HTTP server is here, as server.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import BaseHTTPServer
import CGIHTTPServer

PORT = 8888

server = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer
Handler = CGIHTTPServer.CGIHTTPRequestHandler

httpd = server(("", PORT), Handler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

My web page, testcgi.html, looks like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="get" action="/cgi-bin/testcgi.py">
<textarea name="comments" cols="20" rows="2">
Type message to GET here...
</textarea>
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Test CGI GET">
</form>
<form method="post" action="/cgi-bin/testcgi.py">
<textarea name="comments" cols="20" rows="2">
Type message to POST here...
</textarea>
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Test CGI POST">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

...and my cgi script is testcgi.py, not sure this matters but here it is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#testcgi.py

import cgi

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

val1 = form.getvalue('comments')

print """
<html>
The form input is below...<br/>
</html>"""
print val1
```

The output I get (running server.py on Ubuntu) is as follows.
GET or POST with input of "Hello Goodbye":

```
The form input is below...
Hello Goodbye
```

POST with the input "Hello/Goodbye":

```
The form input is below...
Hello/Goodbye
```

GET with the input "Hello/Goodbye" returns the contents of the file testcgi.py as above.

As far as I can tell, other special characters (\ : % & and so on) all work ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have re-discovered a security issue with the older Python version you are running. See [issue #21766](http://bugs.python.org/issue21766); Python 2.7.6 and newer include the fix.

The `CGIHTTPServer.CGIHTTPRequestHandler.is_cgi()` method does not URL-decode the URL path before checking if it is a CGI script that is referenced.

The bug report contains a work-around, but be advised that since 2.7.3 was released the module has had several related bugs fixed before *and* since that security issue was reported. You may want to just grab the [latest revision](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/CGIHTTPServer.py) from the Python mercurial repositories; there have been several other fixes since 2.7.3 was tagged on 2013/04/09 you'll want to have.

Comment: Thanks Martijn Pieters for this informative and practical solution.  The workaround given in #21766 did not work for me, but I swapped out my CGIHTTPServer.py for the current version and that did the trick.  This is better than my previous workaround, which was to use POST instead of GET.

Comment: @BicycleBobJob: and also avoids a security problem where a malicious 3rd party can inspect your CGI source code! Yes, the #21766 workaround relies on the other changes between 2.7.3 and that bug report to have been applied too.